# Codeigniter Migration cannot redeclare class

Tags: codeigniter, database-migration

I am trying to add reset function to codeigniter's migration. Below is my code:

```
class Migration extends Backend_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('migration');
  }

  public function index()
  {
    //...
  }

  public function reset()
  {
    $this->migration->version(1);
    $this->db->truncate('ci_sessions'); 
    $this->migration->current();
  }

}
```

It returns error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Migration_Create_geo_data in D:\web_projects\vProject\framework\application\migrations\002_create_geo_data.php on line 44
```

If I run them seperately, all are okay. When together it gives error. Any idea?

Comment: Can u elaborate more and check for any re declarations.

Comment: @VJSai Actually I have 4 migration file `001_...` to `004_...`, I have different names and appropriate class names. I can run `->version(1)` or `->current()` without any error, if I run one command only. When I try to run more than one migration command in the same function it gives error.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, this error is a result of setting your migrations to create tables if they do not already exist AND cache data not being updated right away.

Your Migration script calls the [`DB_forge::create_table`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html#create_table) method which takes two parameters. Parameter one is the table name and parameter two is optional. It is the `if_not_exists` flag. The default value is false however; if it is set to true tables will only be created if they do not already exist.

If your tables are created with the `if_not_exists` parameter set to **false** the caching issue will (probably) never happen:

```
$this->dbforge->create_table('table_name');
```

If tables are created with the `if_not_exists` parameter set to **true**, you will need to force the cache to update when reloading your migrations.

```
$this->dbforge->create_table('table_name', TRUE);
```

---

Here are a couple options to avoid this issue:

1. Only send the table name as a parameter to the `create_table` method
2. Unset `data_cache['table_names']` after the `migration->version(0)` call

If you choose option 2, here is a method that works:

```
public function reset() {
    $this->load->library('migration');

    if (!$this->migration->version(0)) {
        echo $this->migration->error_string();
    }

    // unset table cache - this will force it to update
    unset($this->db->data_cache['table_names']);

    if (!$this->migration->current()) {
        echo $this->migration->error_string();
    }
}
```

---

In addition to this, the migration files are autoloaded and saved in the session. 
I changed this line in system/libraries/Migration.php: `include $f[0];` to `include_once $f[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you made a migration by copy/pasting from an earlier one & now have two migration files with the same class declared

ie,

```
class Migration_Add_blog extends CI_Migration
```

in two files