# How to run [Codeigniter] migration using cron Jobs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, migration

i enable cli request only:

```
if ( ! $this->input->is_cli_request() ) {
          echo 'Only access via command line.';
          exit;    
      }
```

tried command with no luck:

```
*/5 *   *   *   *
cd /home4/shah/public_html/proof/oinvoices/;
php index.php migrate reset;
php index.php migrate latest;
```

i want to run two function first i want to reset the database then called the latest version of the migration .

neither error is shown nor it works.

Comment: So what's wrong? What happens / doesn't happen when you run the cron? Do you get any error messages? Make it easy for us to help you, include all the information we need.

Comment: it doesn't work ,no error seen

Comment: Do you have SSH access on your server ?

Comment: yes i have ,but what if i don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to provide path to php.exe then the function path.

i assumed you have php version 5.3,

```
/opt/php53/bin/php /home4/shah/public_html/proof/oinvoices/index.php migrate reset
/opt/php53/bin/php /home4/shah/public_html/proof/oinvoices/index.php migrate latest
```

if you like to run a single cron job ,first make a function in migration:

```
 public function clean_up(){
   if (!$this->migration->version(0)) {
        echo $this->migration->error_string();
    }

    // unset table cache - this will force it to update
    unset($this->db->data_cache['table_names']);

    if (!$this->migration->latest()) {
        echo $this->migration->error_string();
    }
  }
```

> then:if you are using php5.3

/opt/php53/bin/php /home4/shah/public_html/proof/oinvoices/index.php migrate clean_up

> if you are using php5.4

/opt/php54/bin/php /home4/shah/public_html/proof/oinvoices/index.php migrate clean_up

hope it solve your problem .

Comment: clean_up function give error ,
cannot declared table blah blah.
if you run again then it goes smoothly without any error.

Comment: follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545942/codeigniter-migration-cannot-redeclare-class) for further details